# Trying to select text in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

please I will like to select only the email in this columns, 
I am using T-sql, the table name is emailfound, and the column is emailfoundcolumn. I am trying to use

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(':', emailfoundcolumn) > 30
            THEN LEFT(emailfoundcolumn, CHARINDEX(':', emailfoundcolumn) - 1)
        ELSE emailfoundcolumn
        END
FROM emailfound
```

this are samples of the value in the columns
    From: jn61@hotmail.com

```
-----Original Message-----From: chll@hotmailcom 
-----Original Message-----From: hain@sondarjee.fr
-----Original Message-----From: f7@yahoo.com
-----Original Message-----From: fualbi@live.co.uk 
-----Original Message-----From: cbo990@gmail.com 
-----Original Message-----From: maather@btinternet.com
```

but the value is just returning the preceding text before the emails in the column

Comment: Try the [`SUBSTRING()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) instead of `LEFT()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `right` as you need the last part of the string

This should work

```
right(@emailfoundcolumn, len(@emailfoundcolumn)-CHARINDEX(':', @emailfoundcolumn) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177601.aspx)**,**[`Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms180040.aspx)** and **[`CharIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)** string functions

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(500)='-----Original Message-----From: chll@hotmailcom '

SELECT Reverse(LEFT(Reverse(@email), Charindex(':', Reverse(@email)) - 2))
```

**Output:** `chll@hotmailcom`